# Java Android Picasso resize image

Tags: java, android, picasso

Sometimes when I resize my image my image is cut , I did this :

```
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(file)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_delete)
            .resize(dstWidth, dstHeight)
            .into(PicassoTargetFactory.getInstance().getTarget(file));
```

and I use Picaso, version: '2.5.2'

What I did wrong ?

Comment: Dunno but can you try with `fit()` and see if it works (https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit)

Comment: @Maxouille ok I will try